# Set range limit for temperature using Alexa Skill with AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm using the Thermostat and ThermostatController interfaces. I want to set a range limit in the temperature, for example, if you are using Celsius, I want that the user can't set a temperature greater than 35, or less than 10.

I've tried to use the ThermostatController.Configuration with the ComponentConfigurationConstraints obj but it didn't work. Does someone know how to set this range?

Comment: Did you try using https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-thermostatcontroller.html#settargettemperature-error-handling? You can use https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-thermostatcontroller-errorresponse.html#temperature-value-out-of-range-example when users set out of range of temperature.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented that on the error response, but I want to avoid those error responses by setting a range limit in the app.